# CXF NullPointerException in OAuthRequestFilter

Tags: java, web-services, rest, oauth, cxf

I'm using CXF 3.1.5 on Glassfish open source 4.1.1, i want to use OAuth with CXF so i included this artifact in my maven pom file : `cxf-rt-rs-security-oauth2`

after this inclusion each request made to the web service gives me `NullPointerException`.

The exception it raises from the filter method OAuthRequestFilter.isCorsRequest, and after some minutes of debugging we've found that : (Code taken from CXF)

```
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context) {
    validateRequest(JAXRSUtils.getCurrentMessage());
}
```

here is the link of this line :
https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/7d1890510a85d4fd7e70faebc56d6685f103621d/rt/rs/security/oauth-parent/oauth2/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/rs/security/oauth2/filters/OAuthRequestFilter.java#L82

this method called `JAXRSUtils.getCurrentMessage()` each request returns `null` and that null causes later in code a `NullPointerException`, but we didn't understand why.

This is the stack trace from Glassfish log:

```
[2016-02-15T23:46:36.459+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=29 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1455576396459] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[lv.lavloz.merrill.cxf.app.API]: Servlet.service() for servlet lv.lavloz.merrill.cxf.app.API threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.filters.OAuthRequestFilter.isCorsRequest(OAuthRequestFilter.java:246)
    at org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.filters.OAuthRequestFilter.validateRequest(OAuthRequestFilter.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.filters.OAuthRequestFilter.filter(OAuthRequestFilter.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerFilteringStage.apply(ContainerFilteringStage.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerFilteringStage.apply(ContainerFilteringStage.java:68)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:301)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:460)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:334)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]
```

i googled for the problem but i didn't found any solution.

Note: This is not a real project, i'm just testing CXF OAuth 2.0 implementation in a new empty project, we're new to CXF and we're folowing the official doc but we can't go forward cuz of this bug/something is missing and we have the intention to use CXF in real project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've replied at http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/NullPointerException-in-OAuthRequestFilter-tp5765933p5765945.html but did not post here as I was not sure it was a definite answer

Comment: For Glassfish Jersey is the problem and for TomEE CXF is the default implementation but i included CXF in war lib folder so the presence of CXF inside the war was the problem on TomEE.